# ManagedIdentityCredential for Azure RelayManagementClient

Tags: c#, azure, identity, relay

For Azure Key Vault I use DefaultAzureCredential. This works great when developing locally and when published to Azure using the app identity. I do not need to store any id's or secrets in the application.

I also need to utilize the RelayManagementClient to manage (CRUD) hybrid connections from the application. I'm unable to find a similar approach to authorization using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Relay package. The constructor for this client accepts a ServiceClientCredentials instance of which there are three derived classes; BasicAuthenticationCredentials, CertificateCredentials and TokenCredentials - none of which are suitable.

I create an instance of ServiceClientCredentials by calling

```
SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
   .FromServicePrincipal(config.ClientId,
                        config.ClientSecret,
                        config.TenantId,
                        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```

But this way I expose the the azure tenant details in the configuration. This isn't such a big problem initially as the config is secured, but I wonder if it's possible to use ManagedIdentityCredentials for this client?

I could store these values in a KeyVault which used the managed identity credentials, but perhaps someone has done this previously.

EDIT:
This is code for adding AzureCredentials to DI container.

```cs
services.AddSingleton(SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity(MSIResourceType.AppService, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use managed identity to auth, just use  [`FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromsystemassignedmanagedserviceidentity?view=azure-dotnet) or [`FromUserAssigedManagedServiceIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentialsfactory.fromuserassigedmanagedserviceidentity?view=azure-dotnet) instead of `FromServicePrincipal` when creating the instance of ServiceClientCredentials. The first one is for system-assigned managed identity, the second one is for user-assigned managed identity.

Comment: Thank you, it works like you stated. It seems there is DefaultAzureCredential for AzureCredentials, but it seems possible to create a decorator that behaves the same way by first trying the managed service then trying VS credentials (if possible).

Comment: @Vincent, Could you please post working code FromUserAssigedManagedServiceIdentity method. It would be great help for me

Comment: I'm sorry @RajendarManda, I only use `FromSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity` - not the other one.

Comment: Ok thank you for update. Could you please send me code?

Comment: @RajendarManda Sorry for the late reply; I've added the code to the original question.